# Is there a way to or operation in sftp get command?

Tags: bash, get, sftp

Something like :

```
filePattern='sor.log*|sor.SOR.log*'
myLocation=/opt/tradertools/omer
clientLocation=/opt/tradertools/omer/sor/from
clientName=vmonitorlmpa
clientUser=root
clientPass=triltest

export SSHPASS=$clientPass

sshpass -e sftp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oBatchMode=no -b - $clientUser@$clientName << !
   mget $clientLocation/$filePattern $myLocation
   bye
!
```

where the `filepattern` is what needs the "or" operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no "or" operator for strings, only for characters (aka range: `[abc]`).

See the [`glob` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) for syntax supported.

---

You can use multiple `get` commands instead.

*(Note that the `mget` is just a `ftp`-compatibility alias to the `get`)*